# Shell script - syntax error near unexpected token `['

Tags: bash, shell

When I open my terminal I get the following error:

```
bash: /home/ai/.bashrc: line 75: syntax error near unexpected token `['
bash: /home/ai/.bashrc: line 75: `if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then'
```

The relevant part of the bashrc file script starting with the comment is as follows:

```
# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases

if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then

    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'

fi
```

What am I doing wrong and how to correct this?

Comment: Can you post the whole file to pastebin or something? I suspect that the error is before line 75.

Comment: @ phunehehe, Hi! I pasted the whole thing at pastebin.com under the name: 
whole bashrc file-amai14
(Here [link] (http://pastebin.com/2scppXxi) 
Please have a look!

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your pastebin link, you're missing an `esac` to end the `case` statement right before the problematic block.

Comment: @ JosephR and @slm. Your answers accepted! Adding esac at the end of the block resolved the problem.

Comment: @user2561310 Thanks. What slm meant by accepting the answer, however, is to click on the tick mark button under the vote buttons to the left of the answer. This lets somebody browsing the question listing know that this question already has a valid answer without the need to actually click on it and read the comments.

Answer (score 1):

The error is most likely occurring before this block of code. For example, if I put this block of code in it's own script and `echo` the aliases lines out:

```
#!/bin/bash

# example.bash
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then

    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    echo "alias ls='ls --color=auto'"
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    echo "alias grep='grep --color=auto'"
    echo "alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'"
    echo "alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'"

fi
```

I get this:

```
$ ./example.bash 
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
```

Which indicates that it's fine.

#### Terminating case block

This block doesn't have a corresponding `esac`.

```
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)

....
```

Comment: @ slm. Thanks! Yes, you are right! Please see my whole bashrc script file at pastebin (link above).

Comment: Adding esac at the end of the block has removed the error!

Comment: @user2561310 - good, please accept either mine or JosephR's answer so that others know your issue's resolved.